# Where should I do std::move for a function parameter passed by &&?

Tags: c++11

For example, if I have a function that moves a vector to a class member:

```
struct A
{
    void f(std::vector<int> && v)
    {
        m_v = std::move(v); //1
    }

    std::vector<int> m_v;
}

void other_func()
{
    std::vector<int> other_v;
    A a;
    a.f(std::move(other_v)); //2
}
```

should I use std::move two times? First when I pass the parameter and second when I assign the parameter to the member? At least the code compiles without the first std::move.

Comment: FWIW: There's almost no reason to require a parameter be passed by r-value reference. Prefer instead to pass by value instead. It doesn't change the number of moves you'll do in this instance, but it's more flexible in case someone needs to pass, say, a const ref vector and they're okay with making a copy. In that way the compiler creates the copy, not the client.

Comment: good idea .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I use std::move two times? First when I pass the parameter and second when I assign the parameter to the member?

Yes.

One move is required since the expression `other_v` is an lvalue.
The other move is required since the exporesion `v` is an lvalue. All id-expressions are lvalues.

Comment: why not to pass the parameter v by & but not by && in this case? As far as I see this will take the same effect and eliminate the need of using the second std::move.

Comment: @Koban then you couldn't pass a temporary to the function.

Comment: so, probably the best option is to pass v by value, isn't it? (and still use two std::move)